# Express: Query to check if the document exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, collections, document

I am developing an application in Express with mongo. I have to check if a particular document exists in the collection. I am doing this:

```
router.route('/').post(function (req, res, next) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var dept = req.body.dept;
    var arr = mongoose.model('User').find({'name': name, 'dept': dept});
    if(arr.length() > 0){
        //do something
    }
}
```

What does `mongoose.model('User').find({'pemail': email, 'password': password});` actually return because when I run the app, it gives me this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

any help?

Comment: You need a callback function inside `find()`. Have a look at here for the correct syntax : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: Well even better would be `.findOne()` but I supect you did not even import `mongoose` into the local scope via `require`. Plus the callback as already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Hamed, that did the work, Kindly put it as answer here...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the call back function, try something like this:

```
post(function (req, res, next) {
   var name= req.body.name;
   var dept = req.body.dept;
   mongoose.model('User').find({'dept': dept, 'name': name}, function(err, user){
       if(err){
            //do something
       }else{
            //do other thing
       }
   });

}
```